# Can I create a constructor in Python UDF for pig? Just like JAVA UDF?

Tags: python, apache-pig

I'm new to Hadoop and Pig Latin. Currently I need to build a python function for pig to process data. There're five parameters that I want to send to this function along with the data. I know that we can write like 'DEFINE udf my_javafunction('$para')' and then call my_javafunction(data) in pig.

I want to know if I could define a class in python udf and write an *init* function to process these parameters before calling the function?

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer to a question if it is *detailed* and *specific* and not formatted in such a way as to solicit yes/no answers.